# What scriptures' verses can help me understand and achieve wisdom in Hinduism?

Tags: vedas

I'm doing some research on "wisdom" and "ignorance" themes through religions and cultures. I recently made an approach on Plato's Socratian point of view about wisdom and piety.

1. Are there some guidelines in Hinduism on how to achieve wisdom?
2. And, which verses could help me in understanding the conception of "wisdom" in Hinduism?

Comment: Bhagwad Gita is the foremost book. Ramayana will also help you understand aspects of human relations and dignity.

Comment: You want to know what Wisdom is? Or how to achieve it?

Comment: By 'wisdom', do you mean '[dharma](http://www.britannica.com/topic/dharma-religious-concept)?'

Comment: @sv. There are many translations of Dharma, including religion, duty, righteousness, but it certainly doesn't mean wisdom.  Being a good man and being a wise man are certainly related notions, but they aren't synonymous.  A literal translation of the word wisdom into Sanskrit would be Viveka.  But in the context of wisdom literatures from around the world, a more comparable notion would be Jnana.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, when I tried looking up what could OP possibly mean by "Plato's wisdom", the couple of hits I found talked about Plato's "ethics/virtues".  (_"…the greatest good for a man [is] to discuss virtue [excellence] every day..."_). Ethics/Virtues/Morality is more closely related to _dharma_ in Hinduism than viveka/Jnana/knowledge/truth. Hence, the reason for my earlier comment.

Comment: @sv. Well, that is an aspect of Plato's thought, but that's not related to his notion of wisdom and how it's acquired.  Look up things like Socratic questioning, aporia, Socrates' quote "the unexamined life is not worth living", Plato's allegory of the cave, Socrates's statement "he is wisest who, like Socrates, knows that his wisdom is worth nothing", Socates' dialogue Thaetetus, etc.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, Plato's allegory of the cave (return to the cave) reminded me of [the monkeys and ladder story](http://www.slideshare.net/shaldag/a-story-about-5-monkeys) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wisdom is the ability to think and act using knowledge, experience, understanding, common sense, and insight.

You can use the word "Enlightenment" instead of Wisdom.

Apart from Epic books you can refer many Saints and yogi words and their Books of them and their followers

I suggest you some links for your reference

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hindu_gurus_and_saints

http://www.hinduwebsite.com/saints.asp

http://www.om-guru.com/

http://hindunavasooryan.blogspot.in/

http://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-saints/hindu-saints-list.html

Answer (score 0):

You might read through this lecture by Vidura on the wisdom of a wise man.

> He that is not deviated from the high ends of life by the aid of
>   self-knowledge, exertion, forbearance and steadiness in virtue, is
>   called wise. These again are the marks of a wise man, viz, adherence
>   to acts, worthy of praise and rejection of what is blameable, faith
>   and reverence. He whom neither anger nor joy, nor pride, nor false
>   modesty, nor stupefaction, nor vanity, can draw away from the high
>   ends of life, is considered as wise. He whose intended acts, and
>   proposed counsels remain concealed from foes, and whose acts become
>   known only after they have been done, is considered as wise. He whose
>   proposed actions are never obstructed by heat or cold, fear of
>   attachment, prosperity or adversity, is considered as wise. He whose
>   judgment dissociated from desire, followeth both virtue and profit,
>   and who disregarding pleasure chooseth such ends as are serviceable in
>   both worlds, is considered wise. They that exert to the best of their
>   might and act also to the best of their might, and disregard nothing
>   so insignificant, are called wise. He that understandeth quickly,
>   listeneth patiently, pursueth his objects with judgment and not from
>   desire and spendeth not his breath on the affairs of others without
>   being asked, **is said to possess the foremost mark of wisdom**. They that
>   do not strive for objects that are unattainable, that do not grieve
>   for what is lost and gone, that do not suffer their minds to be
>   clouded amid calamities, are regarded to possess intellects endued
>   with wisdom.

[Mahabharata Udyoga Parva, Section 33]